# Is there any way that we can expect indent in tslint to accept either spaces or tabs?

Tags: node.js

I'm using tslint,
We are recently started using tslint. In some lines of code, we have 4 indent spacing whereas in some lines of code we have used tab spacing. Can somehow we make valid both of them, so that our time is not consumed in setting either onr of them?